# $\mathbb E[|X_T|]$ when $\mathbb E[T]<\infty$

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Let $T$ be a stopping time and $X$ a stochastic process such that $X_t \in L^1$ for any $t\ge 0$. Suppose that the stopping time has finite expectation. What can be said about $\mathbb E[|X_T|]$? Is it bounded by the product of the expectation of $T$ and some constant which does not depend upon $T$?

The application I have in mind is the case where $X$ is a Brownian motion.
In one case, I would like to consider the subcase where $T$ is even bounded.

Have a nice day,

Kehrwert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X_t$ is merely integrable, then you can really say nothing. Take, for example, $X_t = f(t)$ (non-random!), then $\mathbb E[|X_t|] = \mathbb E[|f(T)|]$ can be even infinite.

For the Wiener process, of course, the situation is different: it is well known that
$$
\mathbb{E} [|W_T|] \le \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[T]}
$$
(since $W_t^2 - t$ is a martingale).

Comment: Just curious, considering that $\mathbb{E}[|W_t|]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}t}$ for any fixed $t \geq 0$, is there any better (or even sharp) constant $c$ for which $$\mathbb{E}[|W_T|]\leq c\sqrt{\smash[b]{\mathbb{E}[T]}}$$ holds for all $L^1$ stopping times $T$?

Comment: @SangchulLee, yes, this is a known question. I don't remember the answer though, so I'll try to find.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that if we set $T=\inf\{t\geq0:|W_t|=a\}$ for $a>0$, then $T$ is $L^1$ and $$\mathbb{E}[|W_T|]=a=\sqrt{a^2}=\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[W_T^2]}=\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[T]}.$$ Anyway, thank you for spending your time on this!